# Using Dissolve Tool in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, fields-attributes, dissolve, parcel

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4.1 and trying to create a mailing list using parcel data. I need the parcel lines to be dissolved if they have the same owner name and are adjacent or adjoining. Afterwards, I need to select the new parcels that are 35 acres or more.

How do I dissolve parcel lines but still keep other attributes associated with the layer such as addresses?

Answer (score 1):

I would dissolve your original parcels by the appropriate attributes (owner name), then select those resulting polygons greater than 35 acres.  Take the centroids of your original polygons and intersect with the selected set of > 35 acre polygons to determine your candidates for the mailing list.

Alternatively, you can avoid the necessity of the centroid and intersect steps if you use “select by location” with the appropriate selection criteria.